# Applying PCA on single image

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision, pca

Firstly I have used annoy for storing my image features and applied PCA with 200 number of feature.

```
num_feature_dimensions = 200
pca = PCA(n_components=num_feature_dimensions)
pca.fit(feature_list)
feature_list = pca.transform(feature_list)
```

Then I added features to annoy index and created annoy tree object

```
annoy_index = AnnoyIndex(200,'angular')  

for i in range(num_images):
    feature = feature_list[i]
    annoy_index.add_item(i, feature)
    
annoy_index.build(40)
annoy_index.save('annoy_micol_prod_index.ann')
```

Now I want to convert an test image for prediction purpose.

**I need 512 feature to 200 feature**

after features extraction of an image i added it to a list. which shape is (1,512).

```
num_feature_dimensions = 200
pcaSingle = PCA(num_feature_dimensions)
pcaSingle.fit(single_feature)
test_img_feature = pcaSingle.transform(single_feature)
```

Then I am getting the following error.

**[ ValueError: n_components=200 must be between 0 and min(n_samples, n_features)=1 with svd_solver='full']**

Comment: what is the purpose of your PCA ?

Comment: I want to search similar image. Thats why extracted features from datasets then applied PCA on them for only 200 top features.  now I want to test it from an external image.  I am unable to apply PCA on single image to get to 200 feature from it.

Comment: it does not make sense with a single image. you have to flatten & stack the whole train dataset ito a huge 2d matrix, then you can reduce it from say, 500 images to 200 eigenvecs

Comment: just see my model extracting feature from a image then its become (1,512). But I want it (1,200) without it i can't test

Comment: what are your image features ?

Comment: using VGG16 for extracting features from single image then applying -> features.flatten() -> flattened_features / norm(flattened_features) then searching this features in stored feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244274/discussion-between-siam-and-berak).